# Can't upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 using iso file

Tags: 14.04, 13.10, upgrade

I have a 64bit ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop and want to upgrade to 14.04. I had the iso file already so decided not to download an extra 3.5 GB. I made a bootable usb flash disk and booted from that. In the installation process it recognizes my 13.10 and I can see the upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 option but it's disabled. I can either install it alongside my 13.10 or replace it? Is there any way to enable that option?

**EDIT:**
Here is a screen shot of the installation options that I get (The first option is grayed and disabled):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade your ubuntu using the ISO, first you need to mount your ISO to the system

sudo mount -o loop /Downloads/ubuntu-14.04-i.iso /media/cdrom0

you have to replace iso path as required.

If a dialogue should popup asking for upgrade - proceed with the on-screen steps.

If that doesn't works - run the below command in the terminal.

gksu "sh /cdrom/cdromupgrade

Hopes this helps,

Comment: Thank you. I tried the first command which returned : mount: mount point /media/cdrom0 does not exist. The I tried gksu "sh /cdrom/cdromupgrade" which didn't output anything and made no difference.

Comment: I finally mounted the iso file. Now I see a cd drive with ubuntu installation files. How can I use this to upgrade?

Comment: The problem is that there is no cdromupgrade in the iso. Any idea why? and if I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To upgrade your ubuntu using the ISO, first you need make a DVD for that. 
so first step is to search: "Start up disk creator" on search panel.
alternative option is open terminal and type  "usb-creator-gtk", this command directly open that software.

now next step is select ISO file and choose output drive. within 15 min your disk is ready to use.

now you u can upgrade and re-install our ubuntu.

Comment: As I've said in my question I have tried that but the upgrade option is disabled.

Comment: I added a screen shot. I'd really appreciate it if you take a look.

Comment: ok i have seen that pic. i dont think so there will be any option now. u can update it through update center or install fresh 14.02 LTS.

Comment: before that please, take backup of all your data.